# Can NSubstitute mock the return of a MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

My tests use lots of reflection. NSubstitute can mock reflected properties (`PropertyInfo`) like this:

```
mock
.GetType().GetTypeInfo()
.GetProperty("SomePropertyName")
.GetValue(mock)
.Returns(someReturnValue);   // NSubstitute does its thing here
```

How do I do something similar for a `MethodInfo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      var mock = Substitute.For<SomeClass>();
      var mi = mock.GetType().GetTypeInfo()
        .GetMethod("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

      mi.Invoke(mock, null).Returns("xxxxXXX");

      Console.WriteLine(mi.Invoke(mock, null)); // -> Write xxxxXXX
    }
  }

  public class SomeClass
  {
    protected virtual string SomePropertyName { get; set; }

    protected virtual string SomeMethod() => "aaa";
  }
```